# Express $\sin(\theta)$ in terms of spherical harmonics

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-harmonics, spherical-trigonometry

So we can express trigonometric quantities in terms of Spherical harmonics, for example $\cos(\theta)\propto Y^{0}_{1}(\theta,\phi)$. Is there a closed expression for $\sin(\theta)$? If not, is there at least some kind of convoluted, numerically accessible expression?

Best,

v.

PS: It seems to be an infinite sum of $Y_{l}^0$ with even $l$, have a look at my numerical estimate:

[image: numerical estimate]

Comment: @nicomezi The spherical harmonics form a complete basis, therefore I am searching for a linear combination of them as an expression for sine.